# Java Decorator Pattern on Strings Using Caesar Cipher

Tags: java

So I'm trying to follow a Decorator Pattern to encrypt and decrypt a string. I got the encryption part to work just fine, but am having trouble calling the decryption from main. I want to use the string that I just encrypted and not the default string again. How can I achieve this?
Below are my classes (there's a lot of them, but they're short)

AString

```
// Blueprint for classes that will have decorators
public interface AString {

    public String getAString();
}
```

PlainString

```
public class PlainString implements AString {

    String test = "thisIsATest";

    public PlainString(){
        System.out.println("Created plain string: " + test);
    }
    @Override
    public String getAString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return test;
    }
}
```

StringDecorator

```
abstract class StringDecorator implements AString {

    protected AString tempString;
    public StringDecorator(AString newString){
        tempString = newString;
    }
    public String getAString(){
        return tempString.getAString();
    }
}
```

EncryptingWriter

```
public class EncryptingWriter extends StringDecorator{

    public EncryptingWriter(AString newString) {
        super(newString);

        System.out.println("Adding Ceasar Cipher Encryption");

    }
    public String getAString(){

        return encryptString((PlainString)tempString); //decorated
    }

    public String encryptString(PlainString aString){
        String s = "";
        int len = aString.test.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            char c = (char)(aString.test.charAt(i) + 3);
            if(c > 'z')
                s += (char)(aString.test.charAt(i)) - (26-3);
            else
                s += (char)(aString.test.charAt(i) + 3);
        }
        return s;
    }

}
```

DecryptingReader

```
public class DecryptingReader  extends StringDecorator {

    public DecryptingReader(AString newString) {
        super(newString);

        System.out.println("Adding Ceasar Cipher Decryption");

    }
    public String getAString(){
        return decryptString((PlainString)tempString); //decorated
    }

    public String decryptString(PlainString aString){
        String s = "";
        int len = aString.test.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            char c = (char)(aString.test.charAt(i) - 3);
            if(c > 'z')
                s += (char)(aString.test.charAt(i)) + (26+3);
            else
                s += (char)(aString.test.charAt(i) - 3);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

DecoratorTester (main)

```
public class DecoratorTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        AString basicString = new EncryptingWriter(new PlainString());
        String encryptedString = basicString.getAString();
        System.out.println("EncryptedString: " + encryptedString);

        DecryptingReader d = new DecryptingReader(basicString);
        System.out.println(d.tempString.getAString());
        //d.decryptString(d.tempString.getAString()); // how can I decrypt the string?
    }

}
```

Comment: something like `DecryptingReader d = new DecryptingReader(new PlainString(encryptedString)); String result = d.getAString();` ? Of course you need to modify your `PlainString` a bit to give a meaningful constructor

Comment: @AdrianShum But how can I turn the String into a PlainString? The PlainString constructor could take parameter of type String which is the encrypted string. But how can I make a conversion. Furthermore, wouldn't that ruin the point of that class being a plain string?

Comment: your `PlainString` should not care about whether it is encryped or not.  It is simply a plain string. Just have a constructor in `PlainString` which takes a `String` and store it as its internal value.  However, imho, your work is a poor choice as an example of decorator....

Comment: That may be the case. Just going off of lecture notes and examples. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what it should look like (base on my comment).

I am renaming your classes to make it more rational , especially in the context of decorator:

```
interface StringProvider {  // an interface that will produce a String
    String getStringValue();
}

class PlainStringProvider implements StringProvider {
    private String stringValue;
    public PlainStringProvider(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }
    @Override
    public String getStringValue() {
        return this.stringValue;
    }
}

class StringProviderDecorator implements StringProvider {
    private StringProvider delegate;
    public StringProviderDecorator(StringProvider delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    @Override
    public String getStringValue() {
        return this.delegate.getStringValue();
    }
}

class EncryptStringProvider extends StringProviderDecorator {
    public EncryptStringProvider(StringProviderDecorator delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }
    // your stuff about encryption
}


class DecryptStringProvider extends StringProviderDecorator {
    public DecryptStringProvider (StringProviderDecorator delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }
    // your stuff about decryption
}
```

so the code to make use of them looks like this:

```
String originalValue = "this is a test";

String encryptedValue 
    = new EncryptStringProvider(new PlainStringProvider(originalValue));

String decryptedValue
    = new DecryptStringProvider(new PlainStringProvider(encryptedValue));

assert decryptedValue == originalValue;
```